# How to fetch the API details from a component folder using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a reusable component that I have created on the components folder where I have all the details from the user that logs in to the system which is a header section.

I am trying to use `getInitialProps` using fetch with `isomorphic-unfetch`.

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const UserdetailsRespone = await fetch("my API url");
    const UserdetailsJson = await UserdetailsRespone.json();
    return { UserDetails: UserdetailsJson.root[0] };
 }
```

In the render method when I log this.props.UserDetails I get `undefined`.
It is the same API fetch as the one I am doing in the pages folder where I am able to fetch an API response. But I am not able to fetch the response in the components folder.

Can someone help me to solve it?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `getInitialProps` in a child component, it won't work. It only works in the default export of every page.
[From official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#caveats)

Edit:
As mentioned by Uzair Ashraf, using `fetch` is the way to go for fetching data in components. You can take a look at [swr](https://github.com/zeit/swr) too.

Comment: Yes i agree, How can we acheive from components folder if i want to fetch data from an API

Answer (score 0):

`getInitialProps` runs server side and client side.  So you will have to be careful how you use it.  I usually use `typeof Window === 'undefined'` to check whether `getInitialProps` is being called server side or not.

If you have a child component that you need to make a call everytime it is mounted, why not stick with `componentDidMount`?

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    const userDetailsResponse = await fetch("my API url");
    const userDetailsJson = await userDetailsResponse.json();
    this.setState({userDetails: userDetailsJson})
}
```

You can access the properties from state instead of props then.